# Mixing Django models and SQLAlchemy in model fields: can it be done?

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

I have several models, with ids defined like this:

```py
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, blank=True, editable=False)
```

I want to be able to use the SQLAlchemy `server_default` option, I tried this way:

```py
id = Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True,
        server_default=sqlalchemy.text("uuid_generate_v4()"),
        blank=True,
        editable=False,
    )
```

but this returned the error `NameError: name 'sqlalchemy' is not defined` (despite sqlalchemy being imported and installed with Pip).

Is there a clean/correct way of making use of this function in a Django model?

example model:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
import uuid

from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ("key",)

    id = Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True,
        server_default=sqlalchemy.text("uuid_generate_v4()"),
        blank=True,
        editable=False,
    )
    key = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
```

The project runs out of a Docker container, in the Dockerfile I have the line:

```
FROM python:3
...
RUN pip install SQLAlchemy
...
```

and I have the following output when I launch my Docker container:

```
Step 39/44 : RUN pip install SQLAlchemy
 ---> Running in 3805568a1773
Collecting SQLAlchemy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/98/56b7155bab287cd0c78dee26258835db36e91f2efef41f125ed6f6f1f334/SQLAlchemy-1.3.6.tar.gz (5.9MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: SQLAlchemy
  Building wheel for SQLAlchemy (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for SQLAlchemy (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/f2/ec/e0/d7deb0c981557e373edf7370574b7001690892afe5fea30c3c
Successfully built SQLAlchemy
Installing collected packages: SQLAlchemy
Successfully installed SQLAlchemy-1.3.6
```

Which leads me to believe that SQLAlchemy *is* installed, but maybe I'm reading too much into it

Comment: You cannot use sqlalchemy field classes when defining Django-orm models.

Comment: @thebjorn That was the impression I was getting. Do you know of a way of implementing something like the `server_default` method in Django? Some kind of equivalent?

Comment: This seems a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but would make a good question if reworded to be about the actual problem: defining server side defaults in Django ORM models.

Comment: Now I know what the issue is, I can ask a more pertinent question

Comment: You can do it by defining your own Django model fields (it's not as difficult as it sounds ;-)